# MS Access and system time settings relation

Tags: date, ms-access, runtime

I have MS Access database query with criteria ...Documents.DATE>Date()...
It's working fine in one computer, where is full Access (2016) intstalled.
But in others where I use Access Runtime verison (also 2016), it's not working.

I have tried this query with .accrd-file in computer with full version and it's also working. What can cause this kind of behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is typically caused by a MISSING reference.

You would go to menu Tools, References and check if any reference is marked MISSING and resolve that. But, as it is a runtime, you may have to create a small test application that lists the references on the machines with the runtime. Here's a module to get you started:

```vb
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit

' Verify Access' external references.
' Returns True if all references are valid.
' Will run quietly, if called with parameter Quiet as True.
'
' Is intended to be called as the first command from the AutoExec macro
' followed by a call to a function - for example CompileAndSave - that will
' "compile and save all modules".
'
' 2018-07-10. Cactus Data ApS, CPH.
'
Public Function VerifyReferences( _
    Optional ByVal Quiet As Boolean) _
    As Boolean
    
    ' Settings for message box.
    Const Title     As String = "Missing Support Files"
    Const Header    As String = "One or more supporting files are missing:"
    Const Footer    As String = "Report this to IT support." & vbCrLf & "Program execution cannot continue."
    Const Buttons   As Long = VbMsgBoxStyle.vbCritical + VbMsgBoxStyle.vbOKOnly
    
    Dim Reference   As Access.Reference
    
    Dim Item        As Integer
    Dim Guid        As String
    Dim Major       As Long
    Dim Minor       As Long
    Dim Prompt      As String
    Dim Broken      As Boolean
    Dim SecondRun   As Boolean
    Dim Result      As Boolean
    
    Do
        ' Loop (a second time) the references and build a list of those broken.
        Broken = False
        Prompt = ""
        For Each Reference In Access.References
            If Reference.BuiltIn Then
                ' Nothing to check.
            ElseIf IsBrokenExt(Reference) Then
                Broken = True
                Prompt = Prompt & Reference.Guid
                On Error Resume Next
                Prompt = Prompt & " - " & Reference.Name
                On Error GoTo 0
                Prompt = Prompt & vbCrLf
            End If
        Next
        
        If SecondRun Then
            ' Only shuffle the references once.
            Exit Do
        ElseIf Not Broken Then
            ' All references have been verified.
        Else
            ' Try to remove the last non-broken reference and add it back.
            ' This will shuffle the Reference collection and may or may not
            ' cause a broken reference to be added back.
            Item = Access.References.Count
            Do
                Set Reference = Access.References.Item(Item)
                If Not Reference.BuiltIn Then
                    If Not IsBrokenExt(Reference) Then
                        ' Record the reference's identification before removal.
                        Guid = Reference.Guid
                        Major = Reference.Major
                        Minor = Reference.Minor
                        ' Remove this reference.
                        Access.References.Remove Reference
                        ' Add back the removed reference.
                        Access.References.AddFromGuid Guid, Major, Minor
                        Exit Do
                    End If
                End If
                Item = Item - 1
                ' Exit loop when a built-in reference is met.
                ' These are always the top ones.
            Loop Until Reference.BuiltIn
            SecondRun = True
        End If
    Loop Until Not Broken
    
    Result = Not Broken
    
    If Result = False And Quiet = False Then
        Prompt = Header & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & Prompt & vbCrLf & Footer
        VBA.MsgBox Prompt, Buttons, Title
    End If
    
    Set Reference = Nothing
    
    VerifyReferences = Result
    
End Function

' Performs an extended check if a reference is broken, as the
' IsBroken property doesn't check for unregistered files. Thus,
' an unregistered reference may fail even if not marked MISSING.
'
' 2018-07-09. Gustav Brock. Cactus Data ApS.
'
Public Function IsBrokenExt( _
    ByRef Reference As Access.Reference) _
    As Boolean

    Dim NotBroken   As Boolean
    
    On Error GoTo Err_IsBrokenExt
    
    ' If the reference is not registered, calling property FullPath will fail.
    ' Even if the file exists in the Virtual File System, GetAttr will find it.
    If (VBA.GetAttr(Reference.FullPath) And vbDirectory) <> vbDirectory Then
        ' FullPath is valid.
        NotBroken = Not Reference.IsBroken
    End If

Exit_IsBrokenExt:
    IsBrokenExt = Not NotBroken
    Exit Function
    
Err_IsBrokenExt:
    ' Ignore non-existing servers, drives, and paths.
    Resume Exit_IsBrokenExt
  
End Function
```